# Share to Facebook button doesn't work in iPad

Tags: ipad, facebook, mobile-safari, opera

The Facebook website itself is fine. But even in the same browser (I tried this with both Safari and Opera Mini), the little blue F for sharing a New York Times article (likewise several similar sites like Vox) brings an Error message. No details except "We are working on it." But I am not having any problem doing this on a desktop, so I think it is Apple or something about my iPad in particular.

Ideas?

Comment: Settings > Facebook ... Are you logged in there? My guess is no...

Comment: I am signed in, although my FB login is not my Apple email address.